# Can I have a local variable in Ruby be named "$name", without it becoming a global variable?

Tags: ruby, variables, global

So in php the notation for a standard variable is:

`$ so $name = 'bob'`

but in ruby `$name = 'bob'` would be a global variable.

but lets say you would like `$name` to be a standard variable like it is in php.

Can you escape `$name` in ruby so its not a global anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, Ruby does not support having a local variable begin with `$`:

```rb
pry(main)> binding.local_variable_set '$foo', [1,2,3,4]
NameError: wrong local variable name `$foo' for #<Binding:0x00007ff71dddac18>
```

Directly from [the Ruby docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html):

> A local variable name must start with a lowercase US-ASCII letter or a character with the eight bit set.

**update**

(hilariously) "yes, but not really", since Ruby supports Unicode:

```rb
pry(main)>  = 4
=> 4
pry(main)> 
=> 4
pry(main)> name = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
pry(main)> name
=> [1, 2, 3]
pry(main)> ﹩name = 'asdf'
=> "asdf"
pry(main)> ﹩name
=> "asdf"
pry(main)> ＄name = false
=> false
pry(main)> ＄name
=> false
```

Comment: is there any way to convert a variable from global to standard to instance? Or do you just have to go and rewrite it?

Comment: suppose if you want to keep the look you could always use a capital Sname looks similar thanks.

Comment: What about `_ = 3` or `_a = 4` (despite what the doc says)?

Comment: I like your examples. Here's another `４ = ３` then `４ #=> ３`.